# Elasticsearch different conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a segmentation ui where the user can build an elasticsearch query based on the following options: the query `contains` or `not_contains` `all` or `any` of the selected conditions.

I have the following possibilites:

- `contains` `all`: in elasticsearch this is a `must` query
- `contains` `any`: in elasticsearch this is a `should` query
- `not_contains` `all`: in elasticsearch this is a

  `must_not {
      bool {
          must [
              ...
          ]
      }
  }` query
- `not_contains` `any`: in elasticsearch this is a

  `must_not {
      bool {
          should [
              ...
          ]
      }
  }` query

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right ... a should query acts like a logical OR and a must query acts as a logical AND and a must_not acts as a NAND